# Keras_ocr fails to import

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use Keras_ocr for a project, but I can't get it to import to my script. I am using tensorflow backend (non-gpu).

Here is the error code I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Cameron/PycharmProjects/NN-1/Test 1.py", line 5, in <module>
    import keras_ocr
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import (detection, recognition, tools, data_generation, pipeline, evaluation, datasets,
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\detection.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import tools
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\keras_ocr\tools.py", line 14, in <module>
    from shapely import geometry
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 18, in <module>
    from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in <module>
    from shapely.geos import lgeos
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 145, in <module>
    _lgeos = CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Library', 'bin', 'geos_c.dll'))
  File "C:\Users\Cameron\Anaconda3\envs\TensorEnv\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I installed keras_ocr via pip.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue where Keras_ocr finds the wrong DLL or can't find it at all. It can be solved simply by updating Keras_ocr or uninstalling and reinstalling keras_ocr.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Python=3.6 and the latest Tensorflow version, after that install keras_ocr.

That should work.